# Unique ip connections in a syslog file

Tags: ip, unique, syslog

I am analyzing a syslog files that have been created as a result of a DDOS attack and would like to a create a list of unique ip connections.Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do your syslog files look like?  What have you tried?  What kind of assistance do you want?

Comment: you can do that with a bit of `grep`, `sort`, `uniq` and `awk` alone.

Comment: I would like get a listing of all unique ips in a syslog file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the IP/Hostname is in field 4:

```
cat /var/log/messages | cut -d\  -f 4 -|sort|uniq
```

Example log message:

```
May 29 18:27:30 10.101.11.31 Myprog[5291]: 20856: Mar 31 06:14:38 EDT: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet1/0/29, changed state to up
```

You may also want to try a tool like [LogZilla](http://www.logzilla.pro) which will make this much easier for analyzing these things.